# Limit Scrolling of HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I implemented Gallery using Horizontal scroll view by referring some tutorials on google. I tried gallery with gallery widget but its crashing on ics. so i went for horizontal scroll view. I implemented it successfully but i want to limit scrolling of it to 1 image at a time like the way we do in gallery.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite more easier with ViewPager. I found now.Pager moves only one item at a time.
I followed 
[View Pager Example in Android Development](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/)